# What is the meaning of -perm -400 in find command?

Tags: linux, unix, find

I found in a text the command `find / -name "foo" -perm -400`. What does the -perm -400 indicate?

Comment: Did you read `find`'s manual page?

Comment: @BlacklightShining The man page says Search for files which have read and write permission for their owner, and group, but which other users can read but not write to.  Files which meet these criteria but have other permissions bits set (for example if someone can execute the file) will not be matched. Using an example of -perm -664

What does this actually mean?

Comment: It means: search for files which are readable only by the owner (i.e., not by group nor by others), irrespective of whether owner/group/others have (pr not) write/execute permissions.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae So that's for this case of  -400, how does it apply to the general case? Does is mean ignore the 0 valued permission bits?

Comment: `man find` tells you what -perm is for, `man 2 chmod` tells you what the bits mean (400 is a hexadezimal number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to correct what I said in the comments: -perm -400 means search for all files/directories for which the owner permission is set to at least read permission, no matter what the remaining bits for group and other are set to. So this search is satisifed also by 477, for instance.

The general case,

```
find . -perm -xyz
```

means: search for files and directories whose

1. owner permission is at least x
2. group permission is at least y
3. other pemission is at least z.

Comment: “At least” being a bitwise comparison? For example, a file whose permissions are `440` would not show up in a `find . -perm -200`, despite the value 400 appearing to be “greater than” 200?

Comment: A bytewise comparison, not bitwise. It would show up: 4>=2, 4>=0, 0>=0. A good example is 402 would not show up if I use -perm -220, because 4>=2, but 0<2, even though 402 > 220. In my answer, I tried to make it clear that the comparison has to be made byte by byte.

Comment: I'm in Docker. I can't understand when I make `docker run --rm debian:wheezy find / -perm +2000 -type f` it returns me a tiny list of few component but `docker run --rm debian:wheezy find / -perm +2001 -type f` returns me a big bunch of components in a huge list. It seems there is no logical here